# Como sobrescrever um HTACCESS raiz em uma subpasta com outro HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho um arquivo `HTACCESS` na raiz de meu projeto. Porem, possuo uma subpasta que também possui um arquivo `HTACCESS`. Mas não estou sabendo como fazer para que o código deste sobrescreva parte do código do `HTACCESS` raiz.

**HTACCESS raiz:**

```
...
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ statics/$1/$2 [L]
...
```

**HTACCESS subpasta:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ test/statics/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura dos diretórios? Por padrão o htaccess vai sobreescrever as regras na pasta e subpastas que ele está, mas ele não afeta o nível acima dele

Comment: por e:. eu tenho um htaccess na raiz e outro dentro de uma pasta que esta na raiz. na raiz possuo um index.php e dentro desta pasta q está na raiz possuo outro index.php.

Comment: E qual o nome da subpasta? É `test`?

Comment: Não. Mas pode ser. Pq tb troquei o nome em "RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ test/statics/$1/$2 [L]". Apenas para o exemplo. No real, ao invés de test está o nome da pasta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

Estrutura Exemplo:

- App > Admin

Dentro de App > .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Options -Indexes
```

Dentro de Admin > .htaccess

```
#Aqui você escreve novas regras
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Olá Fernando, isso é exatamente o que eu fiz a cima em meu exemplo e não funcionou!

Comment: Você pode usar a técnica de escrever qualquer coisa no arquivo .htaccess para confirmar que ele esta sendo aplicado ao site ou sistema. Ex: escreva TESTE em qualquer linha do arquivo e veja se vai gerar um erro, se não gerar seu .htaccess não esta sendo aplicado. Assim indica que o modulo do servidor (apache) pode não está ativado ai você já tem um caminho pra pesquisar.

Comment: Fiz o teste que você mencionou e o resultado foi, ele está lendo os dois arquivos, pois quando eu escrevo qualquer coisa em qualquer um deles, eu recebo um erro interno do servidor. Então os dois arquivos estão sendo lidos pelo servidor, mas por algum motivo o segundo não sobrescreve o primeiro em suas regras.

Answer (score 0):

Você só pode sobrescrever as regras que não estão com flags [L]:

A flag **QSA**, informa que somente QUERY_STRING poderá acessá-las.
A flag **NC** (nocase), é para ignorar case sensitive (caixa alta/baixa).
A flag **L** (last) é um sinalizador para indicar que a regra atual deve ser aplicada imediatamente, sem considerar outras regras (ou seja, ela se torna independente e prioriária).
A flag **R** (redirect) provoca um redirecionamento HTTP (quando houver o domínio ou servidor escrito na URL do navegador).

As regras funcionam de cima para baixo.
Somente quando a regra já foi aplicada é que a próxima regra será lida.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma condição antes para cada caso:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} = seusite.com
...aqui viria a regra sob a condição acima
```

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente nas subpastas eu uso assim, adiciono o nome da pasta em RewriteBase:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nomedapasta/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E coloco dentro da pasta em questão. No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nomedapasta/

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ statics/$1/$2 [L]
...
```